# How to have a dark layer over the full screen (with opacity) but under a FloatingActionsMenu which is present in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, overlay

I have a fragment inside an activity and it is not "full screen". In this fragment I have a FloatingActionsMenu and I would like this : when I click on this button menu ant its children appear, I want to have a layer dark with a bit of opacity UNDER all the float buttons but over the entire screen.

I'm trying this approach : to create a custom dialog view that contains my buttons and show it when the menu button is clicked. It seems to be complex because I have to be sure that the buttons in dialog are at the same position of button in fragment. Is' there a better and simple way to do this ?
Thank you
GiGi

Comment: I will suggest that you have this semi-transparent layer always in your view  hierarchy but hide it at the beginning. When you click an action item, toggle the visibility of the semi transparent layer. Now to the next question, how to get this semi transparent layer  - Custom dialog might not be the most suited thing. Try a container layout like a framelayout with a custom background (try it , not sure)

Comment: @Dibzmania thanks for your suggestion. That would be great but I don't know how to have a view in my fragment (like FrameLayout) at "full screen mode"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library:

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu_yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/jump_from_down"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/jump_to_down"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#444"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#FFB805"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#F2AB00"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#D99200">
```

[image]

to use it:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
}
```

Comment: this is good but I want to cover with opacity the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Toolbar / not using ActionBar you should be able to put a dark semi-transparent view in your Activity's layout over all of the the other views, except for the Menu, and then change the visibility of that view from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE when the menu is shown.